# datagridview to datatable without updating

Tags: c#

When I insert data from dataGridView to DataTable like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = (DataTable)(dgv.DataSource);
```

any changes in `dgv` automatically updates in `dt`. But I need to copy *the first* data from `dgv` without any updates in future. How can I achieve this?

Comment: im dont really understand what you want but try cloning the datatable

Comment: what do you mean when you say 'the first data'?

Comment: store the first data to database.